# Increase PYKD heap_stat performance, disabling RtlValidSecurityDescriptor

Tags: python, performance, windbg, pykd

While working with [heap_stat](https://github.com/goldshtn/windbg-extensions/blob/master/heap_stat.py) (a Python script based on PYKD library for running Python scripts in a Windbg environment), I'm getting frustrated by the enormous time this script needs for doing its job.

So, I've started a profiling session, using "[Very Sleepy](http://www.codersnotes.com/sleepy/)", and this gave following result:

```
Name                        Exclusive  Inclusive  % Excl.    %Incl.   Module
RtlValidSecurityDescriptor   2561.56s   5123.12s   50.00%   100.00%    ntdll
ZwWaitForSingleObject        1280.78s   1280.78s   25.00%    25.00%    ntdll
NtUserWaitMessage            1279.73s   1279.73s   24.98%    24.98%   win32u
```

As you can see, most of the time is spent in a function, checking some validity (which I don't think is needed). Is there a way to disable this check (Windows configuration, registry setting, ...)?

**Edit after first comment**
As an `xperf` analysis has been requested, I've performed following `xperf` commands:

Start the profiling:

```
xperf -start "DDS_LoggerName" -StackWalk ObjectCreate+ObjectDelete+ObjectReference -heap -Pids 28068
```

Stop the profiling:

```
xperf -stop "DDS_LoggerName"
```

I've opened the result (incomplete, because I first wanted to see what the result looks like) using the `Windows Performance Analyzer`, but it makes no sense to me. I believe my `xperf` configuration is bad. How do I need to start up an `xperf` profiling in order to be able to measure which function takes which amount of time?

Comment: started an issue on the pykd backtracker:
https://githomelab.ru/pykd/pykd/issues/36

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I saw your xperf log anf here you are results:

25% CPU got call 
heap_output = dbgCommand('!heap -h 0').split('\n')

75% loop
for heap_block in heap_output:
and the main CPU consumer is pykd.ptrPtr

The main cause of CPU loss is massive calling dbgeng!FlushCallbacks internally by Debug Engine. In Fact, all Debug Engine funciton recall this method and I don't understand why.

I can advice you to have refactored heap_stat.py and rewrite your own ptrPtr funciton with ptrDword or ptrQword, it may decrease CPU losses.

Comment: we will try to investigate this case

Comment: I imagine you have been using Windows Performance Analyzer for making your analysis? Which report did you view in order to see these results? (Or do you need PYKD symbols for this?)

Comment: Unfortunately, I've just tried replacing `ptrPtr` by `ptrDWord` and the performance looks similar.